# Show that this set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

**Ñotation:**

$V$ is a vector spaces of real functions $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$;
$\{g_1,...,g_m\}$ is a subset of $V$;
$\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is a subset of $X$, where $x_i\neq x_j$ when $i\neq j$;
$v_i=\left (g_i(x_1),...,g_i(x_n)\right )$ for all $i=1,...,m$;
$\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to prove that if $\{g_1,...,g_m\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ is linearly independet. Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not correct. For example, it is possible that the functions $g_1, \ldots, g_m$ are linearly independent as functions even though they share a common set of zeros $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. In that case $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m $ are all the zero vector, and so that collection is dependent.

Comment: For a concrete example, say $g_1 = \sin(x)$, $g_2 = \cos(x)$, and $x_k = \pi k$.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no more information given I think this is false: Suppose $\,X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}=\;$ a set with three elements, and let $\,n=2\,$ , i.e. we choose $\,\{x_1,x_2\}\subset X\,$ .
Take now

$$g_1(x_j)=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;j=1,2\\0&,\;\;j=3\end{cases}\;,\;\;g_2(x_j)=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;j=1,2\\2&,\;\;j=3\end{cases}\;,\;\;$$

Thus, $\,\{g_1,g_2\}\;$ is a linearly independent set in $\,V\,$ , yet

$$\{v_1=(g_1(x_1),g_1(x_2))\,,\,v_2=(g_2(x_1)\,,\,g_2(x_2))\}=\{(1,1)\,,\,(1,1)\}\subset\Bbb R^2$$

is trivially linearly dependent.