# How to show all eigenvalues are positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could you help me to show that the following matrix has all its eigenvalues positive?

$$H=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)^2 & \sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)g_2(x_k) & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)g_m(x_k)\\ 
\sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)g_1(x_k) & \sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)g_m(x_k)\\ 
 \vdots& \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ 
\sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)g_1(x_k) & \sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)g_2(x_k) & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $g_1,...g_n$ are linearly independent real functions and $x_i\neq x_j$ when $i\neq j$.

Thanks.

Comment: $x_i$ are concrete numbers, not variables, as implied by your question about eigenvalues being positive, right? Even if the $g_i$ are linearly independent and $x_i\neq x_j$, it would still be possible for $g_h(x_i)$ to equal $g_k(x_j)$ for all $i,j,h,k$. So then the determinant would be $0$. Where did the question come from? Are you sure this is the right question?

Comment: I want a generalization of result in page 404, with $P(x)=\sum a_ng_n(x)$ instead of $P(x)=\sum a_nx^n$. Can you help me? The link is: http://me.yazd.ac.ir/ebrahimi/courses/NumericalMethods/numerical%20methods.%20faires%20&%20burden.pdf

Comment: $g_j(x)=\sin (jx)$ and $x_k=k\pi$ yields $H=0$. The eigenvalues are nonnegative as $H=GG^T$ is positive semidefinite. Not necessarily definite.

Comment: How to prove that $\sin(x),...,\sin(mx)$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)^2 & \sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)g_2(x_k) & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)g_m(x_k)\\ 
\sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)g_1(x_k) & \sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)g_m(x_k)\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
\sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)g_1(x_k) & \sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)g_2(x_k) & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)^2
\end{bmatrix}$

$=
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1(x_1) & g_1(x_2) & \cdots & g_1(x_n)\\ 
g_2(x_1) & g_2(x_2) & \cdots & g_2(x_n)\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
g_m(x_1) & g_m(x_2) & \cdots & g_m(x_n)
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
g_1(x_1) & g_2(x_1) & \cdots & g_m(x_1)\\ 
g_1(x_2) & g_2(x_2) & \cdots & g_m(x_1)\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
g_1(x_n) & g_2(x_n) & \cdots & g_m(x_n)
\end{bmatrix}=AA^T$

Here $A=\begin{bmatrix}
g_1(x_1) & g_1(x_2) & \cdots & g_1(x_n)\\ 
g_2(x_1) & g_2(x_2) & \cdots & g_2(x_n)\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
g_m(x_1) & g_m(x_2) & \cdots & g_m(x_n)
\end{bmatrix}$

Let $\lambda$ be an eigen value of $H$ then $\exists 0\ne v\in V$ such that $Hv=\lambda v$

Let $\left<,\right>$ be the standard dot product,

$\lambda\left< v,v\right>=\left< v,\lambda v\right>=\left<v,AA^tv\right>=\left<A^tv,A^tv\right>\ge 0$

As $v\ne 0$ so $\left< v,v\right>>0\Rightarrow \displaystyle \lambda =\frac{\left<A^tv,A^tv\right>}{\left<v,v\right>}$

So $\displaystyle \lambda =\frac{\left<A^tv,A^tv\right>}{\left<v,v\right>}\ge 0$

Comment: How do we know that the columns of $A^t$ are linearly independent?

Comment: As  "$g_1,...g_n$ are linearly independent real functions and $x_i\neq x_j$ when $i\neq j$"

Comment: Do you get it @PerguntadorDeperguntas ???

Comment: I think that the matrix $A$ is $A=\begin{bmatrix}
g_1(x_1) & g_1(x_2) & \cdots & g_1(x_m)\\ 
g_2(x_1) & g_2(x_2) & \cdots & g_2(x_m)\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
g_m(x_1) & g_m(x_2) & \cdots & g_m(x_m)
\end{bmatrix}$, ok?

Comment: yes, its rows are linearly independent(its columns are also linearly independent).... so the columns of $A^t$ are linearly independent(its rows are also linearly independent)

Comment: But, what do you think about the post on the following link? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422015/show-that-this-set-is-linearly-independent

Comment: The columns of $A^T$ need not be linearly independent. This matrix is only positive semidefinite.

Comment: @julien then can we say that the eigen values are positive???? I dont think so......

Comment: No. Only nonnegative.